# NodeJSでTypedArrayをファイルに保存して後に読み込みたい

Tags: javascript, node.js

プログラム内で使っているTypedArrayをファイルに保存して、後に読み込みたいのですが下のようなコードでは期待する動作になりません。
何が問題でどのように解決すればよいのでしょうか？

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const i32arr = new Int32Array([255, 256])
// Int32Array [ 255, 256 ]
console.log(i32arr)

fname = 'hoge'
fs.writeFileSync(fname, i32arr)
const buf = fs.readFileSync(fname)
const i32arr2 = new Int32Array(buf)
// Int32Array [ 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ]と表示される
// ここで [ 255, 256 ]と表示されてほしい
console.log(i32arr2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コンストラクタを下記のように書き換えると正しく動作します。

変更前: `new Int32Array(buf)`
変更後: `new Int32Array(buf.buffer, buf.byteOffset, buf.byteLength / Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT)`

バイナリファイルの書き出しはご質問の`fs.WriteFileSync`で問題ありません。
[`fs.ReadFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options)の戻り値が[`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_buffer)である点がポイントです。

公式ドキュメントの[`Buffers and TypedArrays`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarrays)を読むと冒頭の変換処理が必要だと記述されています。
`Buffer`は[`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array)の性質を持っているため new *TypedArray*(*Buffer*) してもうまく動作しないことが原因です。

本家SOの類似回答:
[Convert a binary NodeJS Buffer to JavaScript ArrayBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31394257/8248751)

日本語の関連ブログ:
[ArrayBuffer と TypedArray でバイナリデータを扱う](https://numb86-tech.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/05/12/134052)

Comment: どうもありがとうございます！ご説明とリンク先のドキュメントを読んで理解が深まりました。